# Regex to match all but zero or more leading or trailing substrings

Tags: regex

I would like to do a regex on a string like the one below:

```
Flag test1 test2 Flag
```

(leading and trailing `Flag` can repeat zero or more times)

What I want to get:

```
test1 test2
```

How to put what I want to an one-based numbered expression? so I can use in a replacement regex later.

Another case:

```
Flag Flag Flag test1 test2 test3 Flag Flag     Flag
```

I want to get:

```
test1 test2 test3
```

I want to get rid of leading and trailing "Flag " repetitions.  (Flag can be followed by any whitespace char.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Flag\s+
```

Replace all occurrences with `""`.

Sometimes, it's simpler to remove what you don't want than to try to match what you do want; regexen can often be applied alternating negatives and positives to be more understandable.